# When (if ever) would you use splice instead of slice in Javascript? (best practices)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been learning about functional programming concepts. One of the core concepts I've read is the importance of limiting the number of functions that modify an external variable to avoid unexpected potential bugs later down the road. 
With that in mind, the material I've been reading has recommended the use of slice over splice as slice outputs a new array without modifying the existing one, where splice will modify the existing array.

Considering that you can do everything with slice that you can do with splice (given it takes a couple extra lines of code), when would you ever use splice over slice to modify an array? I'm wondering what kinds of scenarios I should consider using the splice method in. My main considerations are that splice may be more memory or CPU efficient to call when dealing with large arrays, since it just removes the value without having to store a "before" and "after" variable holding both sections of the array surrounding the value you wish to remove and then concatenating them back together. Also, it sounds like it could be more memory and CPU inefficient to use slice and would become even more of a bad idea, the larger the array is (a linear function of increased computational power used). But, perhaps my considerations are wrong or there are other cases I haven't thought of. Any feedback is more than welcome. I'm just trying to gain a deeper understanding of when the "pure functions" (functions that don't modify external variableS) concept is not applicable or isn't best use.

Here's an example of how I see slice as functionally capable of doing everything splice can:

```js
array = [1,2,3,4,5];

//using the splice method

array.splice(3,1);
// array is now [1,2,3,5]

//using the slice method

function replaceSplice(arr){

let sliceBefore = arr.slice(0,3);

let sliceAfter = arr.slice(4);

let modifiedArray = sliceBefore.concat(sliceAfter);

}

replaceSplice(array);

// returns a new array called modifiedArray with the values [1,2,3,5]
```

Comment: please add some formatting to the question.

Comment: Alright, just give me a sec to figure out how to modify the post and I'll break up the text at the top. Sorry, this is my first question.

Comment: `splice` mutates the original array, `slice` doesn’t. `splice` returns the sliced out elements, `slice` returns the sliced array.

Comment: It really boils down to a philosophical question. Both methods have their place and have been there more or less from the beginning of (JavaScript-) time. I certainly have use cases for both of them and like them both!

Comment: Right. I understand how the methods work. I was more asking about when it's ever a good idea to use splice (in terms of computational efficiency mostly) instead of doing the same thing with slice, as I wrote out above)

Comment: I think efficiency is not really the issue here, you have worked out yourself, how both methods work and any programmer will have to decide whether to use one or the other on the basis of writing in an "immutable", "functional" or "easy to read" style.

Personally I am glad that nobody tells me which one to use when .. ;-) #freedom_to_act

Comment: In functional programming, you'll probably not use `.splice()` a lot for the reasons you mention. ( immutable data ) . Keep in mind that the 3rd parameter and more inserts new element, so `.splice()` can be handy to both remove and add in one command. In non-functional programming, where immutable data is not a requirement, this can happen more often.

Comment: And do not worry ( too much ) about computational efficiency in javascript.  If the array is so large that a choice between `.slice()` and `.splice()` matters for efficiency, you want to chunk the array or handle it in a web worker so that you do not have to loop it fully in one go in the main script. For example pagination of a collection of articles, since you only have room to render 5 articles in sight.

Answer (score 2):

With `.slice`, you're creating two copies of the array and then merging them. That's not very optimal, `.splice` on the other hand can be as fast as the underlying array implementation is.

Additionally in general, it's usually better to have methods that do what they say, even if there's an alternative. Both `.slice` and `.splice` could be reimplemented using a simple `for` loop, but both are nice to have for various purposes.

Comment: Hmm yeah, I can see where you're coming from. The course I'm going through doesn't seem to be a big fan of splice because it doesn't follow the functional programming concept of not modifying external variables, but I'm sure that in a lot of cases it's just more efficient or more practical to do so.

Comment: @Shwei I would think whoever wrote the course should have chosen a language that supports pure functional programming. JavaScript standard library objects are not purely immutable. And when working with arrays, making too many copies may sometimes hurt your performance. When it does not, I'd sugest using `.map`, `.filter` and friends, which always return a copy and do not change the array. Using `.filter`, you can do immutable splice on one index like this: `[0,1,2,3,4,5].filter((unused, index)=>index!=3)` but I would not recommend it unless you need to avoid changing the array.

Comment: Yeah, you're really hitting on a big part of my question, which is how creating new variables to store data impacts overall application performance (in terms of both CPU and memory usage). That's interesting that javascript objects are not purely immutable. Is that still true if you use the Object.freeze() method? Also, that's an interesting application of the filter method I'd never considered. Thanks for sharing it!

Answer (score 1):

splice is mutating existing array whereas slice creates a shallow copy of the array.
Use splice when you want to add/delete items from the original array.
Use slice when you want to copy the array.

In old js days slice was used to copy arguments into an array

```js
function () {
  typeof arguments.map; // => 'undefined'
  var copy = [].slice.call(arguments);
  typeof arguments.map; // => 'function'
}
```

You can't insert items in the array with slice, but you can do it with splice.
Example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
var months = ['Jan', 'March', 'April', 'June'];
months.splice(1, 0, 'Feb');
// inserts at index 1
console.log(months);
// expected output: Array ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March', 'April', 'June']

months.splice(4, 1, 'May');
// replaces 1 element at index 4
```

Use like push

```
months.splice(months.length, 0, 'May');
// expected output: Array ['Jan', 'March', 'April', 'June', 'May']
```

Choosing whether to use mutation or not can depend on different factors. But in general, try to avoid mutation in code. Immutable code is less error-prone, easy to test and produces fewer side effects.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of `[].slice.call(arguments);`, such nostalgy! +1! I do not miss it thoug :D

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you that it's better to keep code immutable when possible. That's interesting that slice used to be a method for adding arguments to an array.

Answer (score 0):

So I have an application written in PHP that naturally uses JS on the front end. This app allows a user to query the students within a school and district. So the flow goes: choose your district, that sends an ajax call to the server to retrieve the schools associated with that district. This then populates the next select field with the appropriate schools based on the district filter. Then based on the school selected, it sends an ajax request to get all the students in that school. The app sends back an array of schools and students that i loop over in the  options. So if I had a check box on each  to hide a particular school or hide a particular student for some reason, I could use splice to remove it from the array without another query to the server. The only reason i'd feel comfortable doing this is because I can just regenerate that array with a new query. I personally have never had a use case for splice on a hardcoded array that wasn't generated from a query of some kind. I'm curious to see if other users have a solid use case for it myself. Interesting question.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. OP's implementation of `splice` could be used for the purposes you use it for.

Comment: Sure, i know that there's ways to use both, i was just giving my own personal use case. I'm curious to see other answers as well.

Comment: This is kind of what I was looking for is use examples. I can see how in your case, using splice doesn't carry the same risk, because the variable that it's editing is a temporary variable generated by the query and because that variable is not the same as the actual array that holds all of the information that the query was generated from, it's somewhat safe to splice it for the purpose of filtering. I think in the example you gave, I'd probably just use the filter() method that doesn't require you to know the exact array location of each school in order to modify the result. Thx for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

> Considering that you can do everything with slice that you can do with splice (given it takes a couple extra lines of code), when would you ever use splice over slice to modify an array?

First of all `slice` can't do what `splice` does and `splice` can't do what `slice` does. The important difference is that `splice` modifies the array in-place and cannot create a shallow copy while `slice` can't modify the array in-place and always creates a shallow copy.

A good example of both would be having a function that accepts an array as parameter and does some sort of transformation:

```js
function someTransformation(array) {
  // Slice the array to create a shallow copy, if you don't do this
  // the input array will be modified which the caller might not
  // expect.
  array = array.slice();

  for (let i = array.length; i >= 0; --i) {
    // Since a copy of the array is used we can modify the array however
    // we want without modifing the original. Splice let us insert an
    // element around each element of the original array with ease. 
    array.splice(i, 0, '-');
  }

  return array;
}

const array = [1,2,3,4,5];

console.log(someTransformation(array));
console.log(array);
```

Comment: You're right. In terms of their mutation and non-mutation properties, they cannot do the same thing. When I said that, I meant in terms of whether they can achieve the same output using both methods, not in terms of whether a mutation is taking place. In that regard, I'm leaning towards implementing in a non-mutational way when possible, but not at the expense of a great deal of CPU and memory usage, which is what the real root of my question was is at what point it becomes inefficient to use non-mutation at the expense of additional memory and CPU usage.